# Using Javascript with MPDF

Tags: javascript, php, html, mpdf, chart.js

I want to use the charts created in charts.js with MPDF but it doesn't seem to be recognising the Javascript elements, do you know if there is anything additional you need to add.

If MPDF cannot render Javascript do you know any other HTML to PDF converter in PHP that will work?

Comment: Javascript and MPDF is not an good combination. I made an javascript that generates an HTML page. This HTML page i converted in PHP to an PDF file. MPDF does not support SVG elements in case you work with charts. They need to be converted to PNG images. If you use for example Highchart than it is possible to create PDf files trought their server.

Comment: @JelleP can you help out how to use highcharts in pdf ..

Comment: Since version 5 mPDF support SVG.
http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=259&searchstring=SVG 

I already integrate some SVG in PDF, Looks great.

Answer (score 0):

Better make charts in PHP using https://phpchart.com/. if you want to show it in a pdf. javascript looks and style does not work in PDF anyway.